# Serialize C++ object to send via sockets to Python - best approach?

Tags: python, c++, serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I need to create a network communication between two different frameworks, one written in `C++` and the other in `Python`.

To exchange data, I want to create some kind of flexible structure (basically a struct) in `C++`, which is serialised, sent through sockets to `Python` and then deserialised.

What is the most common way to do this? I'm sure that `Boost` could do it on either side, since there is `boost python`, but I don't want to blow up the project requirements that much. So is there maybe a smaller library or whatever another elegant solution except specifying an own binary data format?

**UPDATE:**

So here is one example how to use Googles `protobuf` to send a data structure from a `C++` script to a `Python` script via `UDP`. This is tested on Mac OS X Mavericks but should work fine on other Unix systems too.

**Installing protobuf**

The first step is of course installing the `protobuf` library. I used [homebrew](http://brew.sh) for the main library and `pip` to install the `Python` modules:

```
brew install protobuf
pip install protobuf
```

Then I defined a very simple data structure using the proto-syntax:

> **Filename: foo.proto**

```
package prototest;

message Foo {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string bar = 2;
  optional string baz = 3;
}
```

This proto-file can now be translated into C++ and Python classes via:

```
protoc foo.proto --cpp_out=. --python_out=.
```

The folder should now contain the C++ header and source files and the Python code:

```
├── foo.pb.cc
├── foo.pb.h
├── foo.proto
└── foo_pb2.py
```

Let's have a look at the very basic `C++` code, which is meant to send an instance of `foo` over the network, using UDP (to localhost on port 5555):

> **Filename: send.cc**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

// this is our proto of foo
#include "foo.pb.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr);
  addr.sin_port = htons(5555);

  // initialise a foo and set some properties
  GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;
  prototest::Foo foo;
  foo.set_id(4);
  foo.set_bar("narf");

  // serialise to string, this one is obvious ; )    
  std::string buf;
  foo.SerializeToString(&buf);

  int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  sendto(sock, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it via `clang++`:

```
clang++ -o send send.cc foo.pb.cc -lprotobuf
```

And finally, this is the `Python` code, which waits for UDP packets and deserialise them into `foo`. Again: no error checking whatsoever, this is only to demonstrate the functionality:

> **Filename: receive.py**

```
import socket
from foo_pb2 import Foo

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5555))

foo = Foo()
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    foo.ParseFromString(data)
    print("Got foo with id={0} and bar={1}".format(foo.id, foo.bar))
```

Now we're done and this is the final directory structure:

```
├── foo.pb.cc
├── foo.pb.h
├── foo.proto
├── foo_pb2.py
├── receive.py
├── send
└── send.cc
```

To test the script, simply run `receive.py` to listen to UDP packets via

```
python receive.py
```

and keep your eyes on the output when you execute the C++ generated `send` script:

```
./send
```

Comment: Sounds like Google's [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) could be a good fit here.

Comment: Translate the objects into XML or JSON?

Comment: JSON is my current solution, did not mention it. Thanks also for mentioning protobuf, didn't hear about it yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for [Protocol Buffers - Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which has enough resource for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [python](/questions/tagged/python). You can make a compatible structure which is readable in both languages.

> Protocol Buffers are a method of serializing structured data. As such,
>   they are useful in developing programs to communicate with each other
>   over a wire or for storing data. The method involves an interface
>   description language that describes the structure of some data and a
>   program that generates from that description source code in various
>   programming languages for generating or parsing a stream of bytes that
>   represents the structured data. [†](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers)

Answer (score 5):

Protocol Buffers' successor, [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org), also has good support for C++ and Python. (Disclosure: I am the author of Cap'n Proto, and also was the author of most of the Protobuf code released by Google.)

Comment: Thanks Kenton, I'll have a look at it!