# Google Protobuf - UDP Communication Between C++ and Python - google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: unpack requires a string argument of length 4

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to send a message between one framework in CPP and another in Python. I followed the same process shown on: 
[Serialize C++ object to send via sockets to Python - best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785155/serialize-c-object-to-send-via-sockets-to-python-best-approach)

My server code in Python is:

```
import socket
from DiceData_pb2 import DiceData

UDP_PORT=1555

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("", UDP_PORT))

dicedata = DiceData()
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print data
    dicedata.ParseFromString(data)
    print ("gyrox = {0}".format(dicedata.gyrox))
    print("gyroy = {0}".format(dicedata.gyrox))
    print("gyroz = {0}".format(dicedata.gyroz))
    print("accelx = {0}".format(dicedata.accelx))
    print("accely = {0}".format(dicedata.accely))
    print("accelz = {0}".format(dicedata.accelz))
    print("roll = {0}".format(dicedata.roll))
    print("pitch = {0}".format(dicedata.pitch))
    print("yaw = {0}".format(dicedata.yaw))
    print("side = {0}".format(dicedata.side))
    print("certainty = {0}".format(dicedata.certainty))
    print("time = {0}".format(dicedata.time))
```

The .proto file is the following:

```
package prototest;

message DiceData {
  required float gyrox = 1;
  required float gyroy = 2;
  required float gyroz = 3;
  required float accelx = 4;
  required float accely = 5;
  required float accelz = 6;
  required float roll = 7;
  required float pitch = 8;
  required float yaw = 9;
  required int32 side = 10;
  required float certainty = 11;
  required string time = 12;
}
```

I know the communication is working, because the server receives the first message and prints it as garbage. However, after it reaches the ParseFromString line, the following error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 13, in <module>
    dicedata.ParseFromString(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/message.py", line 185, in ParseFromString
    self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1095, in MergeFromString
    raise message_mod.DecodeError(e)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

Does anyone knows how can I solve this? I know the string is not empty because there is garbage being printed on the previous line, but I can't seem to be able to convert the string back to the data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ code in the question you linked to was broken. It contains this line:

```
sendto(sock, buf.data(), strlen(buf.c_str()), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

This is wrong! It will cut off the message at the first zero-valued byte. It should look like this instead:

```
sendto(sock, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

This would definitely cause the error you are seeing.

I have edited the other question to add this fix.